# Auto incremento ID valor

Tags: mysql, auto-incremento

No meu MySQL Workbench tenho 4 tabelas com o id de auto incremento.

Mas quando preencho o formulário ele acrescenta valores não seguidos.

Por exemplo:

Preencho um formulário pela primeira vez e o ID que ele me coloca é o 3.

Eu quero que o Id seja seguido. Existe alguma forma de contornar ou corrigir isso?

Comment: Tem alguma razão específica para começar do 1, ou é apenas curiosidade?

Comment: Quero que comece do inicio. porque as outras tabelas que estão ligadas tambem começam do numero 1

Comment: Logo na primeira vez? penso assim... Se você tem 3 tuplas na sua tabela com id's 2,3,4 e você apaga a linha com id = 4, Ficando Somente 2,3 quando for inserida um novo registro, este será o de numero 5. Ficando dessa Forma 2,3,5. E isso está totalmente correto. é Isso ou estou fazendo confusão? Esclareça melhor a pergunta...

Comment: Até pode estar certo. e acho que sim. Mas testei a tabela no primeiro registo e começou no 3.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode também alterar o valor da propriedade caso tenha perdido a sequência caso tenha removido algum registro.

```
ALTER TABLE `TABELA` AUTO_INCREMENT = ?;
```

No **?** você substitui para o valor que desejar.

Se precisar dos dados não precisa fazer o truncate só isso vai resolver.

Answer (score 2):

Dê um truncate na tabela, ele irá resetar o auto-increment.

Nota.: se sua tabela tiver registros que não deseja perder, faça um backup antes:

```
TRUNCATE [TABLE] tbl_name
```

[Mais na documentação do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/truncate-table.html)