# Como resetar o valor auto_increment (SEM TRUNCATE)?

Tags: mysql, auto-incremento

Como posso fazer para resetar/reiniciar o valor do `AUTO_INCREMENT` no `Mysql`, sem o uso de `TRUNCATE`?

Pois, em alguns casos, não é possível usar `TRUNCATE table` em algumas tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `ALTER TABLE` para fazer isso.

É possível "resetar" uma tabela da seguinte forma:

```
DELETE FROM tabela;

ALTER TABLE tabela AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Você também pode definir outro valor inicial para `AUTO_INCREMENT` ao invés do `1`.

Exemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

Comment: Que bom que achou a solução sozinho! :)

Comment: Não achei a solução sozinho. No SO temos uma opção onde é permitido fazer a pergunta e, ao mesmo tempo, postar a resposta. Isso é útil quando você sabe de alguma coisa que pode ser importante pra outra pessoa (note que a publicação da resposta e a pergunta têm o mesmo horário)

Comment: veja se isso também é útil para você, quem sabe você possa ajudar esta pessoa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5415/auto-incremento-id-valor/5421#5421